# Doctrine/PostgreSQL not running every update on my script

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm running a dozen update statements on a script and some updates just won't happen, I need to know why and how to fix this situation.

I have this piece of code:

```
foreach($clis as $c => $cli)
{   
   //... do some stuff

   foreach($emails as $e)
   {
            $Mailqueue = $this->em->getRepository('Sendsys\Entity\Mailqueue')->findBy(array("email" => $e,"status" => "P"));
            foreach($Mailqueue as $queue)
            {
                $queue->setStatus('S');
                $this->em->persist($queue);
            }               
    }
    $this->em->flush(); //entity manager is retrieved before that
}
```

This basically run through a (somewhat large) table to update the emails with status 'P' to 'S', these emails are on a list in the $emails array.

I have tried using doctrine's **ExecuteUpdate** with a prepared statement instead of retrieving and  persisting an entity each time , but it results in the exact same issue.

Some more details:

The issue happens  even with the mail sending function commented out

I know that all of the emails are being sent (when uncommented) and the script  is generating all of the update statements, I've output them when testing ExecuteUpdate

I know that the updates are getting to Postgres because some rows do update and if I refresh the rows will randomly update until there is none left

I can't just update everything afterwards, I need to know where the script stopped in case of failure.

*EDIT*

It's not doctrine related, I've connected directly to the database and ran the followings statements inside a loop:

```
    $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE mailqueue SET status = 'S' WHERE status = :status AND email LIKE :mail"); 
    $stmt->execute(array( ':status' => 'P', ':mail' => $e )); 
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: gez, this went into limbo real fast

Comment: I have no idea what you want to know because at no point in time do you actually ask a question.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions  I hope this is better like this:

I'm running a dosen update statementes on a script and some updates just won't happen, I need to know why and how to fix this situation. 

for example: I create 12 update statements and only 5 or 6 happen on the actual database, the rest is lost;

Maybe some table locking issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements of updates are run only at the end by $this->em->flush();
This is the only action that tells Doctrine to begin the SQL transaction, if you need updates te bo executed before that, just call the flush method.

During the treatments before flushing, the changes remain in the entities linked to the manager.

Comment: right, but why only a few of the statements are being are being run, even thought the script does go past that point.

and even the executing a query with pure PDO yelds the same problem :/